# Java reflection: automatically invoke the right overloaded method based on parameters and signature

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

Say have an overloaded method called `doTask`:

```
public class Game {
  void doTask(Joker joker);
  void doTask(Batman batman, Robin robin);
}
```

I would like to invoke the right method, given the name of the method (`"doTask"`) and an array of parameters whose number and types are not known a priori.

Normally, this involves three steps at least:
1. Find the number of the parameters and their types, and make an array `Class[] myTypes`.
2. Identify the correct overloaded `Method`, i.e. `Method rightMethod = game.getClass().getMethod("doTask", myTypes);`
3. Invoke the method: `rightMethod.invoke(paramArray)`.

Does there exist a facility to ask Java reflection to automatically identify the right overloaded method to use, and save us from having to do Steps 1 and 2? I'm thinking ideally, this would be like:
`Library.invoke("doTask", paramArray);`

Comment: This sounds somehow wrong to me. What are you trying to achieve here? Why don't you know the number of params? Where do you get them from? What form do they have? When you don't know the number of parameIers, how can you be sure there is an implementation with the right number of arguments? Is it an option to pass the list of parameters directly to `doTask()` and let the implementation decide what to do with them?

Comment: Overloading: comes with some minimal design smell. Reflection: even bigger smell. Long story short: what is the underlying problem that you intend to solve here?

Comment: lupz and GhostCat, I agree with you in that if I'm writing the entire project from scratch, this would not be written this way. As it stands, the `doTask()` methods have already been written (and used by other code). I'm writing an wrapper function, `myFunc(Object... paramArray)`, with additional business logic, to call the right `doTask()`.

Comment: The other option would of course be to write a separate wrapper for each of the overloaded `doTask()` methods. But that would duplicate much of the business logic code, and make it difficult to maintain.

Comment: is this `business logic` the same for all params? if No, then you already can recognize which `doTask()` should be called using one wrapper method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is such a facility, [`java.beans.Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Statement.html), resp. [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Expression.html) if a return value is needed:

```
Game game = new Game();
Joker joker = new Joker();
Statement st = new Statement(game, "doTask", new Object[]{ joker });
st.execute();
```

However, it only works for `public` methods.

Also, unlike `java.lang.reflect.Method`, this facility has not been adapted to support *varargs* parameters, so you have to create a parameter array manually.

It can be demonstrated, that it does the work of selecting the right target method based on the argument types, which are not necessarily identical to the parameter types:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
class Foo implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }
}
// has to choose between submit(Callable) and submit(Runnable)
// given a Foo instance
Expression ex = new Expression(es, "submit", new Object[]{ new Foo() });
Future<?> f = (Future<?>)ex.getValue();
System.out.println(f.get());
es.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I was initially stumped by "argument types not necessarily != parameter types", but I think the meaning is this: `new Foo()` is of type `Foo` (the argument type), which is not identical to `Callable<>` (the parameter type). But since `Foo` is a subclass of `Callable`, the right `submit` will be called. Am I right @Holger?

Comment: Also, since `Expression` and `Statement` are in the beans package, they only work for JavaBeans classes, right?

Comment: @Holger oh damn... Had no idea this would exist

Comment: @flow2k: right, just calling `getMethod("submit", argument.getClass());` would fail as there is no `submit(Foo)` method, so the implementation has to check each method for applicability, as Gerald Mücke elaborated. Thankfully, this has already been implemented. Regarding “Java Beans”, the bean pattern is so broad that it matches almost every class. The only constraint has been mentioned in my answer already; it only works for `public` methods. This has been demonstrated by my example, it uses `ExecutorService` and the inner class `Foo` and neither does any explicit action to be a Java Bean.

Answer (score 2):

First - to answer your question - no, there is no such facility.

Second, step 2 is a bit more complicated as it doesn't suffice to create a class array from the parameters and call `getMethod`.

Actually you have to iterate over all methods, that match the name, number of arguments and compare the argument types of the method for assignment compatibility for the given argument types (i.e. `methodArgType.isAssignableFrom(paramType)`), to ensure that compatible subtypes of the method arguments types are correctly reflected. Things get slightly more complicated with varargs.

Comment: Widely unknown, [there is such a facility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590933/2711488)…

Comment: @ Gerald Mücke Thanks for your input. Regarding your comments on Steps 2 and 3, it appears you can simply do, for Step 2: `Class[] argTypeArray = new Class[paramArray.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < paramArray.length; n++){
            argTypeArray[n]=paramArray[n].getClass();
        }`

Comment: `Method rightMethod = Game.class.getMethod("doTask",argTypeArray)`

Comment: Finally, for Step 3, `rightMethod.invoke(game, paramArray)`.