# Java enum anonymous inner class and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have an enum with anonymous inner class like:

```
public enum Status {

    PRELIMINARY() {
    @Override
    boolean process() {
        return true;
    }

    SUBMITTED() {
    @Override
    boolean process() {
        return false;
    }

    abstract boolean process();

}
```

I have a model like

```
public class Foo {

    private Status status;

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I need to use reflection to set a `Foo.status` like:

```
private static <T> void setFieldValue(Foo instance, Class<?> klazz, Object value) {
    try {
        Class<?> aClass = value.getClass(); // Is Status$1 instead of Status
        Method method = klazz.getDeclaredMethod(getSetterName('setStatus'), aClass);
        method.invoke(instance, value);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        if (!klazz.equals(Object.class)) {
            setFieldValue(instance, klazz.getSuperclass(), fieldName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This works when `Status` does not contain an inner class and is a simple enum, however for the above `Status` class it will throw a `NoSuchMethodException`. This is because the class of my value will be `package.Status$1` instead of `package.Status`.

Is there a good work around for this?

Comment: Not to be too picky, but your example code is missing some brackets and your reflection example seems completely irrelevant since there is no method that could correspond to the invocation.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've updated my code to better reflect my problem.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590933/2891664) might help you out. However, I'd question why exactly you're using reflection here, since you seem to know an awful lot about the method you're invoking ahead of time.

Comment: Only in this heavily simplified example... In the wild, I'm generating a DynamicJasper report where the user can specify arbitrary columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your means of locating the desired method.  Something like the following should work:

```
private static @Nullable Method findMethod(Class<?> klass,
                                           final String methodName,
                                           final Object... args) {

    @Nullable Method candidate = null;

    classSearch:
    while (klass != null) {

        // Check all the class' methods for a matching one.
        methodSearch:
        for (final Method method : klass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (!method.getName().equals(methodName)) continue;

            final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length != args.length) continue;

            // Check all parameters can come from the given args.
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (!parameterTypes[i].isInstance(args[i])) continue methodSearch;
            }

            candidate = method;
            break classSearch;
        }

        // No matching method, check super class.
        klass = klass.getSuperclass();
    }

    // May be 'null' if no match was found.
    // Throw an Exception if this isn't a valid outcome in your case.
    return candidate;
}
```

Chaining this with your existing code (calling `.invoke` on the returned `Method` (if it's not `null`)) should give you the desired outcome.